# Java DXA 1.4, Linux server issue Tomcat is not starting

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

We are facing issue with SDL Web 8.1.1 and DXA Java 1.4 hosted on one of our Linux Tomcat servers.

All microservices are working fine and we are able to get full page on Windows developer machine using Discovery service hosted on same Linux box.

Moreover we have hosted same Java DXA 1.4 War to another Linux server with Tomcat 8 where it is working fine.

We are getting below error in the logs when we are starting Tomcat 8.

> 15:59:37.468 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerComponentPresentationProvider': Injection of resource dependencies failed;
>   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tridionSpringConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies f
>   ailed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.dd4t.providers.PayloadCacheProvider com.sdl.web
>   app.config.TridionSpringConfig.cacheProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cac
>   heProvider': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:30
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tridionSpringConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.dd4t.providers.PayloadCacheProvider com.sdl.webapp.config.TridionSpringConfig.cacheProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheProvider': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]

Please let me know where we are missing something.

Comment: We are facing the same problem on Mac and Linux. Basically the problem seems to be a circular reference between two libraries. My guess is one of the Autowired Classes in: com.sdl.webapp.tridion.SpringContextConfiguration com.sdl.webapp.config.TridionSpringConfig It might be: @Autowired public PayloadCacheProvider cacheProvider; We are using DXA Java 1.7.0 with Spring 4.3.7.RELEASE - the same war archive with the same Tomcat will work on Windows (thats very curious). May Bart help us? Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tr

Comment: @Sascha-MatthiasKulawik I've converted your "answer" into a comment since it is not an answer but a follow up question. I think it makes sense that you ask your question separately and refer to this one, but please don't abuse the answers for it, you might want to follow the https://tridion.stackexchange.com/tour